# Some dict properties in seaborn set_style function don't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
X = np.arange(20)
y = np.log(X**2)

# set title in Chinese
plt.title('你好')

sns.set_style({'axes.facecolor':'red','font.sans-serif':['SimSun']})
sns.lineplot(X,y,color="blue")
```

When I run this code first time in Jupyter,the title can be shown correctly, that means the `font.sans-serif` property worked well, but the backgroundcolor is not red.
But when I run the **same code** again for the second time, the `axes.facecolor` property works,the backgroundcolor changes to be red.
That makes me confused, why did this happend? And is there any other property like this?

Comment: `.set_style` is meant to be used as a global property. I usually execute these right after my imports, not in the middle of my working code. Executed in the order i've described, this doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [seaborn style aesthetics configuration tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html), local style control should be done with (for instance):

```py
with sns.axes_style("darkgrid"):
    sns.lineplot(X,y,color="blue")
```

For global settings, use `sns.set_style(...)` **before** any plotting statement in order to it to be taken into account. This is why you have to launch it twice in Jupyter to take effect. Dedicating a cell to it right after the import could be a better solution.

Comment: I just tried this inside a function in a script with `rc={'figure.figsize': newsize}` but it was ignored. Originally tried `sns.set_style` inside the function and it didn't work either.